# How to return highest value of a column in excel in terms of numerical number?

Tags: excel, max

[image]

How can I get cell A3 to reflect the the highest value in terms of the bigger numerical number of cloumn A  be it a positive or negative value?

Comment: 10 is the bigger and higher number...now if you want the number that is furthest away from zero that is a different story.  You want the maximum of absolute values?

Comment: @ForwardEd looks like OP wants the number furthest away from zero

Comment: The number furthest from 0 is a better way to phrase it. How can i get that? No absolute plz, need to reflect the +/- symbol as well

Comment: Just saw your no abs... is this for a large number of values or just two?

Comment: if you do have 5 and -5 which one do you want picked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(Max(A1:A32)>abs(MIN(A1:A32)),MAX(A1:A32),MIN(A1:A32)
```

Check to see if the absolute maximum is bigger than the absolute value of the minimum.  If the max is larger, stick with the larger value and perform a max calculation.  If absolute MIN is larger, then just perform a MIN calculation and you will maintain your sign.

Comment: Good question asked, actually I would like to reflect the furthest negative value from the column. Which will have multiple of rows (e.g A1-A32)

Comment: furthest negative value will just be MIN.  if you mean you want negative in the event of a tie the formula stands as is.

Comment: That can work too, the negative value is much preferred in the event of a tie. Thanks for the big help

Answer (score 1):

`=IF(ABS(MIN(A1:A2))>ABS(MAX(A1:A2)),MIN(A1:A2),MAX(A1:A2))`

Assuming no two values are the same.

```
-15
15
```

will result in `15` being displayed.